How to delete all the exact same elements in inspect element console
I have this webpage I saved on my computer that i edited everything i didnt need out of it on inspect element
Im trying to now remove the text inside each profile im following
i found the exact element of each one and their <Div class= their dir= their style= and their bis_skin_checked=
what ever that is, are all the exact
so i figured if i can just find a script to plug into console that deletes or removes all elements like for example delete all A and all A from the wepage are deleted
i could achieve what i want without the tedious work of removing from each one which is 700 by the way
here is the exact entire element
i need every thing on the webpage that has this element to be removed so it disappears off the screen
dir="auto" style="text-overflow:unset;color:rgb(15,20,25)" bis_skin_checked="1"

